# Does QEMU emulate TLB?

Tags: x86, qemu, emulation, tlb, device-emulation

I have a very simple question, does QEMU emulate TLB? What happens when a guest linux system executes an "invlpg" instruction as it is for the invalidation of a TLB entry. I am aware that QEMU has softmmu [link](http://vm-kernel.org/blog/2009/07/10/qemu-internal-part-2-softmmu/) which is used for translating the guest virtual address to host virtual address but does QEMU emulate an actual TLB, and what is the effect of "invlpg" instruction. Or does QEMU simply ignores this instruction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is somewhere between "yes" and "no". QEMU doesn't attempt to emulate the actual guest CPU's TLB (which is a piece of hardware which accelerates lookups from guest virtual addresses to guest physical addresses). However it does implement its own rather similar data structure which it calls a TLB -- this accelerates lookups from guest virtual addresses directly to host virtual addresses for RAM, or from guest virtual addresses to the read/write functions for emulated devices.

Since there are similarities between the CPU TLB and QEMU's TLB, we can use the guest instructions to invalidate or otherwise operate on the TLB as the triggers to perform QEMU TLB invalidations (which is what the tlb_flush_page() call in helper_invlpg() is doing); so these instructions are not simple no-ops. We also lie to the guest and tell it plausible things about the size of its TLB if it uses the cpuid instructions which query cache and TLB information. But we don't actually model the guest TLB -- so you won't see performance changes around the size of the guest TLB, and you can't log information about guest TLB hits and misses, and we don't implement TLB lockdown on CPU architectures that have it.

Finally, the monitor "info tlb" command is rather misnamed, because it's actually displaying information about the guest's page table setup, which is nothing to do with the TLB state.

Comment: when you say guest CPU's TLB, is it point to TLB which is virtualized in Guest environment with vCPU?

Answer (score 4):

> does QEMU emulate TLB?

**Yes.**

---

The QEMU monitor console provides an [`info tlb`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Monitor#info) command which will

> list the TLB (Translation Lookaside Buffer), i.e. mappings between physical memory and virtual memory

---

The [CPU emulation documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/donut-release/docs/CPU-EMULATION.TXT) has a section that says

> The page cache is called the "TLB" in the QEMU sources.

---

In the source code, namely [`target-i386/cpu.c`](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=target-i386/cpu.c;h=ed7e5d5de32a7026d657377875509e18a93ae4f7;hb=HEAD#l139) we see the following definitions related to the TLB:

```c
/* TLB definitions: */

#define L1_DTLB_2M_ASSOC       1
#define L1_DTLB_2M_ENTRIES   255
#define L1_DTLB_4K_ASSOC       1
#define L1_DTLB_4K_ENTRIES   255

#define L1_ITLB_2M_ASSOC       1
#define L1_ITLB_2M_ENTRIES   255
#define L1_ITLB_4K_ASSOC       1
#define L1_ITLB_4K_ENTRIES   255

#define L2_DTLB_2M_ASSOC       0 /* disabled */
#define L2_DTLB_2M_ENTRIES     0 /* disabled */
#define L2_DTLB_4K_ASSOC       4
#define L2_DTLB_4K_ENTRIES   512

#define L2_ITLB_2M_ASSOC       0 /* disabled */
#define L2_ITLB_2M_ENTRIES     0 /* disabled */
#define L2_ITLB_4K_ASSOC       4
#define L2_ITLB_4K_ENTRIES   512
```

---

In [`target-i386/translate.c`](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=target-i386/translate.c;h=094cec059ca406acdc0b56e28a3319795f8f5078;hb=HEAD#l7424), we see the following code handling the `INVLPG` instruction:

```c
    case 7:
        if (mod != 3) { /* invlpg */
            if (s->cpl != 0) { 
                gen_exception(s, EXCP0D_GPF, pc_start - s->cs_base);
            } else {
                gen_update_cc_op(s);
                gen_jmp_im(pc_start - s->cs_base);
                gen_lea_modrm(env, s, modrm);
                gen_helper_invlpg(cpu_env, cpu_A0);
                gen_jmp_im(s->pc - s->cs_base);
                gen_eob(s);
            }
        }
```

`gen_helper_invlpg` is implemented in [`target-i386/misc_helper.c`](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=target-i386/misc_helper.c;h=4aaf1e4d95ee336d0e5034d04624825fab137ae3;hb=HEAD#l177):

```c
void helper_invlpg(CPUX86State *env, target_ulong addr)
{
    X86CPU *cpu = x86_env_get_cpu(env);

    cpu_svm_check_intercept_param(env, SVM_EXIT_INVLPG, 0); 
    tlb_flush_page(CPU(cpu), addr);
}
```

where it calls `tlb_flush_page`, which is implemented in [`cputlb.c`](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=blob;f=cputlb.c;h=38f21511666171b7e18f20b1575f9fe5a11903a2;hb=HEAD#l84).

---

So you can see that **yes**, the `INVLPG` instruction *will* flush the TLB for an address.

Comment: Just a question, I was wondering is it possible to manage and emulate virtual cache system with QEMU? So a system like this: "virtual address from CPU" -> "Virtual Cache(VIVT or VIPT)" -> "TLB" -> "Memory(DRAM)". Instead of a conventional system which is    "virtual address from CPU" -> "TLB" -> "Cache(PIPT)"  -> "Memory"