# Does QEMU RISCV system emulation emulate tlb cache?

Tags: cpu-architecture, qemu, riscv

I have been playing around with this blog-post https://colatkinson.site/linux/riscv/2021/01/27/riscv-qemu/ and after booting up the machine with this command:

```
qemu-system-riscv64 \
    -machine virt \
    -cpu rv64 \
    -m 1G \
    -device virtio-blk-device,drive=hd \
    -drive file=overlay.qcow2,if=none,id=hd \
    -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net \
    -netdev user,id=net,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 \
    -bios /usr/lib/riscv64-linux-gnu/opensbi/generic/fw_jump.elf \
    -kernel /usr/lib/u-boot/qemu-riscv64_smode/uboot.elf \
    -object rng-random,filename=/dev/urandom,id=rng \
    -device virtio-rng-device,rng=rng \
    -append "root=LABEL=rootfs console=ttyS0" \
    -nographic
```

i tried viewing system cache with command `lscpu` which showed:

```
Architecture:          riscv64
  Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
  On-line CPU(s) list: 0
NUMA:                  
  NUMA node(s):        1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0
```

And no info about TLB caches.

I am assuming that -machine virt is the main source of the problem but every other machine I tried didn't boot up.

Comment: The answer to this doesn't vary across guest architectures, so it is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070691/does-qemu-emulate-tlb/29112195#29112195